# BigQuery Streaming inserts with timestamp and unique row id

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

How can we insert a timestamp and unique row id while inserting/streaming the data into a table using java SDK?

```
        Map<String, Object> metadata = new HashMap<>();
        metadata.put("table_name", "Users");
        metadata.put("timestamp", Instant.now().toString());
        metadata.put("Id", UUID.randomUUID(););
        metadata.put("is_processed", false);


        Queue<Map<String, Object>> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        queue.add(metadata);

        // convert the entries in queue to List<RowToInsert>
        List<InsertAllRequest.RowToInsert> rowsToInsert = queue
                .stream()
                .map(mapEntry -> InsertAllRequest.RowToInsert.of(mapEntry);)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        // prepare InsertAllRequest
        InsertAllRequest insertAllRequest = InsertAllRequest
                .newBuilder(getTableIdInstance("MetaData"))
                .setRows(rowsToInsert)
                .build();

        InsertAllResponse insertAllResponse = bqClient.insertAll(insertAllRequest);
```

Currently, I am using java functions to generate UUID and timestamp but checking bigquery can do this by default

Comment: Set the column that will be the unique row id as the Primary Key with Auto Increment, and pass a NULL to that column on the insert.  Set a column for the date, have its default value be "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" and pass it a NULL on insert.. thats how its done in theory.

Comment: Do you want to use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP along with the data?

Comment: @easleyfixed I don't see any option for data type with a primary key, and also, when I am passing null for timestamp field, I get an error message saying timestamp field can't be null

Comment: @PoalaAstrid yes i am looking for CURRENT_TIMESTAMP along with the data

Comment: @RaviTeja can you provide the code you're working on(if it's not confidential), the schema, and your sample data?

Comment: @PoalaAstrid added sample snippet

Comment: Alter the table - when you set the primary key you also need to set it to "NOT NULL" , "AUTO INCREMENT".  It is probably set to allow nulls is why you got that error.

Comment: And for the DateTime you need to  set it to "NOT NULL" and  set its default value for "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" and if that won't work try setting the default to this instead "NOW"

Comment: @RaviTeja is your schema nullable?

Comment: @PoalaAstrid schema is not nullable. All fields are mandatory

Comment: @PoalaAstrid, below is the schema 

`
table_name        STRING          REQUIRED
timestamp.         TIMESTAMP.  REQUIRED
Id.                        STRING.         REQUIRED
is_processed      BOOLEAN.     REQUIRED
`